# Initialized list shown as empty in method

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
serial_list=[]
dev_label = ["0","0"]
context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='block',device_type='partition')
observer = GUDevMonitorObserver(monitor)

print dev_label


def device_connected(observer, device):
    print dev_label

    flag =False
    for iden in serial_list :
        if iden == device.__getitem__('ID_SERIAL_SHORT'):
            flag=True

    if flag ==False:

        Welcome.device_count+=1
        print Welcome.device_count
        serial_list.append(device.__getitem__('ID_SERIAL_SHORT'))
        dev_label[Welcome.device_count-1]=str(device.__getitem__('ID_FS_LABEL'))
        label = gtk.Label('Device connected :: {0!r}'.format(dev_label[Welcome.device_count-1]))
        Welcome.vbox.pack_start(label)
        Welcome.window.show_all()

    if Welcome.device_count<2:
        label = gtk.Label('Connect the second device')
        Welcome.vbox.pack_start(label)
        Welcome.window.show_all()


    else :
        Exchange()

observer.connect("device-added",device_connected)
monitor.start()

class Welcome:
    device_count = 0    
    window = gtk.Window()
    vbox= gtk.VBox(False, 5)


    def __init__(self):

        self.window.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.window.set_title("Welcome")

        label = gtk.Label("Connect the desired device")

        self.vbox.pack_start(label)
        self.window.add(self.vbox)

        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda q: gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.show_all()
```

here is the traceback :

```
['0', '0']
[]
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 36, in device_connected
    dev_label[Welcome.device_count-1]=str(device.__getitem__('ID_FS_LABEL'))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

As you can see the list,`dev_label`,is initialized to `["0","0"]` in the beginning. However, this list is shown to be empty in `device_connected` .someone please tell me what is going wrong !

Comment: please print out `Welcome.device_count-1`, let's see what its value is. What makes think `device_connected` is empty?

Comment: `Welcome.device_count-1` is 0 ... `dev_label` is empty in `device_connected` because it is shown to be so in the traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 36, in device_connected
    dev_label[Welcome.device_count-1]=str(device.__getitem__('ID_FS_LABEL'))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range, I didn't see that.

Comment: The problem is most likely that it's not running from the same thread within GTK, try passing it through the `context`

Comment: @Wolph how do I do that?

Comment: @VineetKaushik: disregard my last comment, I've just looked up the API you're using (next time, please note which library you are using) and the `Context` object doesn't do what I would expect from something named `Context`. It most likely has something to do with the observer system you are using but I don't have a machine where I can test the `pyudev` lib right now.

Comment: @Wolph I figured out what was wrong (With someone else's help though.) The problem was with the `Exchange` class which hasn't been included in this code. The values in `dev_label` were being popped in Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

`Welcome.device_count` has value of `0`, and so you are assigning a value as

```
array_name[0 - 1] = str(...);
```

So, `Welcome.device_count` is what is causing error.

Thanks!

Comment: You missed the `Welcome.device_count+=1` I think ;) Also, the `print` shows it's empty so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanku sire wolf :) thku thuku terpe